# How can I prevent an event from causing its own event from firing in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, treeview

I have a treeview with checkboxes and I have the following handler for the "AfterCheck" event:

```
private void trvAvailableFiles_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_isCheckingInProgress)
    {
        trvAvailableFiles.BeginUpdate();

        var nodePath = e.Node.Tag.ToString();
        bool isChecked = e.Node.Checked;
        e.Node.Nodes.Clear();

        try
        {
            _fileTreeLogic.GetChildNodes(e.Node, true);
            e.Node.ExpandAll();

            _isCheckingInProgress = true;
            SetChildrenCheckState(e.Node, isChecked);
            _isCheckingInProgress = false;

        }
        finally
        {
            trvAvailableFiles.EndUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

If you look closely you'll see that I'm checking if "_isCheckingInProgress".  If it is not, then I proceed and expand all the nodes and call the SetChildrenCheckState() method.  The problem I have encountered is that SetChildrenCheckState() will subsequently cause each child node to all fire the AfterCheck event for its own node.

My question is, is there a more clean way to allow the first AfterCheck event to fire but not the subsequent ones?  It seems kind of hackish that I have to have an instance bool variable to check and set.

Comment: @Viquish I have done it this way before, seems perfectly reasonable to me.

Comment: You *might* be able to use the sender parameter to see what caused the event to be raised, but I'm not sure what will populate it the first time. So it might not be useful. :)

Comment: Is there something wrong with my proposal (which repeats the advice given by the MSDN) that prevents it from solving your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One recommendation you'll see occasionally around SO is to not put a lot of code into event handlers themselves. There are a number of reasons for this. First, in your case it would be easier to understand a call like:

```
private void trvAvailableFiles_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (!_isCheckingInProgress) 
    {
        _isCheckingInProgress = true;
        try { GetAvailableFiles(); } catch {}
        _isCheckingInProgress = false;
    }
}
```

And to place the rest of your code in `GetAvailableFiles()`. This creates a separation between event code and action code which most people would agree is a worthwhile distinction to make.

Second, which may or may not be applicable in your case is that multiple events can cause the same action. Such as `mnuFileQuit_Click` and `btnClose_Click` as an obvious example. If both make calls to `CloseApplication()` it removes a lot of redundant code.

Comment: While I generally agree with the argument that one should strive to minimize the amount of code placed into event handler methods, there seems little justification for handling the `mnuFileQuit.Click` and `btnClose.Click` events in separate methods.

Comment: @Cody - I'm sure there are better examples of the principle I'm trying to convey in my second point. Sometimes two events cause a lot of the same (but not all) side effects and usually the differences have to do with the event itself. But I confess none better are coming to me at the moment. It's been a while since I've used forms development.

Comment: +1, since I reference pulling out the code (albeit without needing a flag) in my answer. As an alternative example, sometimes one event causes stuff to happen that can also happen without the event being triggered.  Personally, I consider the three possible alternatives to this to be bad form (i.e., duplicating the code, explicitly triggering the event, and calling the event handler function directly).

Answer (score 8):

Use: `if(e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)` instead of `if (!_isCheckingInProgress)`.  See [`TreeViewAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeviewaction.aspx) .

When the user uses the keyboard or mouse to check the checkboxes, `e.Action` will be `TreeViewAction.ByKeyboard` or `TreeViewAction.ByMouse`.

The MSDN provides this as example code for the [TreeView.AfterCheck Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercheck.aspx).

Edit 1: Obviously, if you're setting the checkbox yourself in code, move the code in the event handler to a new function and have the code that sets the checkbox call it directly.  The point of this solution is to let you use event handlers for user input without having those events get triggered when you set the checkboxes yourself via code.

Edit 2: See Spencer's answer for an explanation of my comment in Edit 1

Comment: Both MSDN pages recommend using `if(e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)` to avoid recursive event triggering chaos.  However, only [`TreeView.BeforeCheck`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforecheck.aspx) goes the extra mile and highlights the warning (and suggested remedy) in yellow.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I use a function that removes and then adds the event.

```
private void trvAvailableFiles_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    EnableEvents(false);
    trvAvailableFiles.BeginUpdate();

    var nodePath = e.Node.Tag.ToString();
    bool isChecked = e.Node.Checked;
    e.Node.Nodes.Clear();

    try
    {
        _fileTreeLogic.GetChildNodes(e.Node, true);
        e.Node.ExpandAll();

        SetChildrenCheckState(e.Node, isChecked);

    }
    finally
    {
        trvAvailableFiles.EndUpdate();
    }
    EnableEvents(true);
}

private void EnableEvents(bool bEnable)
{
    if(bEnable)
        cbWhatever.OnChecked += EventHandler;
    else
        cbWhatever.OnChecked -= EventHandler;
}
```

Comment: **My God, really?** All that to avoid setting a flag that you test once at the top of your code? What's the advantage?

Comment: I do like this this because it prevents the expense of the needless event calls.

Comment: @Viquinish: It does if you ignore the expense of *two* calls to a method to add and remove the event handlers, and the process of adding/removing the event handlers itself.

Comment: @Cody, the tree can get pretty deep.  Making a hundred unnecessary method calls if it can be avoided seems reasonable.

Comment: Yes really, it keeps the code cleaner and easier to maintain. :)

Comment: 100 unnecessary calls (i.e., calls that will run pretty much instantly) is nothing compared to making code less readable.  Though really, I don't consider this code especially unreadable.

Comment: That's just nuts. How do you figure that calling an additional method to add and remove event handlers is cleaner or easier to maintain than setting a global flag? No matter how noticeable the event calls may or may not be (I'm siding with not), this example is always going to be *significantly* more expensive. Think through what's actually happening.

Comment: @Cody, there is no way this is more expensive.  Compare making 2 calls removing some event bindings to making a call to this event handler for every child node in the tree.

Comment: It is straight forward and easy to understand.

Comment: @Viquinish: Because you've abstracted away the implementation details, you automatically think the resulting code is simpler and "faster". However, once you understand the internal implementation of events, then the cost of adding and removing them becomes immediately apparent. Of course, this is all a purely theoretical exercise. I'd be willing to bet you a significant sum of money that were you to *benchmark* the two approaches, the change in execution time would be virtually immeasurable.

Comment: @Cody, The removal of two event handlers (adding or removing a delegate from a list) is O(1).  The calling of this event handler for every node is O(N).  You are right for small N, it won't matter.  But you can't say that the repeated method calls and branch are free.

Comment: Yeah I'd just stick with the "wtf, this is weird" argument. It *is* weird and though it works it *will* make any other developer looking at it scratch their head for a bit. But hey, if you don't plan on letting anyone else look at your code and it doesn't confuse you then have at it.

Comment: @King: I didn't say it was free. I'm questioning the merit of the alternative. 100 items is still a "small" N.

Comment: @Spencer: That attitude of "no one else will ever have to look at or maintain my code, so I can do what I want" is inevitably a mistake. You should always write code for others to read. Even you are a different developer several years down the road. And it's not particularly uncommon that you later decide to share your code with someone else, open source a personal project, or even ask a question regarding your code on a site like Stack Overflow...

Comment: @Cody - I didn't intend to condone such an attitude and yes, I agree with you.

Comment: @KingNestor: Sure, but you might be able ignore it as being irrelevant.  If the unnecessary event call is couple of orders of magnitude faster than other O(N) things happening at the same time (e.g., actually setting the checkboxes), you can ignore it regardless of the size of N.  This may or may not be the case.

Comment: (I know this thread is old but) instead of `EnableEvents`, try calling it `PreventEventBubbling(event)` and pass the current method as event parameter and change the code to only prevent the current event. It will make your code more readable and it's a method that's easily expandable to be used in any such situation.

Comment: @Abel I like the idea of a single call over 2 but I'm not sure how to implement a `PreventEventBubbling(event)` function in C#. Care to elaborate?

Comment: If you want to have a single call, implement `IDisposable` and use `using`. Alternatively, use attributes, which might actually be more readable in this case, but you may need a DBC library (several exist for .NET/C#). Just a single call is not possible, because calling a destructor is non-deterministic in .NET.

Answer (score 1):

No, there's no cleaner way to do what you've shown. I'm not really sure why you feel that variables are a "hack" approach. Setting a flag is a common technique used when writing UI code.

The real hack would be some obscure way to prevent raising the event the *first* time, but not subsequent times. Future maintenance programmers are guaranteed to understand how setting a flag works; they're not guaranteed to appreciate the "elegance" of your alternative approach.

Comment: I guess I didn't like the fact that I was forced to have an instance variable.

Comment: @Viquinish: What do you think is wrong with instance variables? And how *else* do you think this could possibly be implemented? That's basically all that's happening when you call the `BeginUpdate` and `EndUpdate` methods; it's just being abstracted away by the framework. (That's not *exactly* how those methods are implemented, but it might as well be.)

Comment: I guess when you put it that way it seems reasonable.  Thanks cody.

Comment: +1 A flag is cheap, clean and readable. We often do this  e.g. `MethodA` will be called if user clicks the button, but won't if the button is *clicked* programmatically.

Comment: @Danny: In the case of a button click, I usually use the sender parameter to indicate if a click was sent programmatically or not.